# changing the position of google maps SupportMapFragment Zoom and My location controls not work

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

I'm trying to change the zoom & my location controls positions in Android Google maps.

I want to set zoom control position at the right bottom and set my location position at the left bottom of `MapFragment` (I'm using the `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`).

Here is my map fragment layout:

```
<fragment
       android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
       class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

The written codes for changing the controls position (`getMapAsync` callback):

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    if (map != null) {
        // Map is ready

        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        View mapView = mapFragment.getView();

        // Zoom control
        @SuppressLint("ResourceType") View zoomButton = mapView.findViewById(0x1);

        if (zoomButton != null && zoomButton.getLayoutParams() instanceof RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) {

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams zp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) zoomButton.getLayoutParams();

            zp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            zp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

            zp.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
        }

        // My location control
        @SuppressLint("ResourceType") View locationButton = mapView.findViewById(0x2);

        if (locationButton != null && locationButton.getLayoutParams() instanceof RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) {

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();

        // position on left bottom
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

            lp.setMargins(30, 0, 0, 30);
    }

}
```

But it doesn't work and I'd like to know what's wrong with my code. Is there a better solution for doing that?

**[Updated - 1]**

My application language is Persian (FA) so I've added `android:supportsRtl="true"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in order to support RTL language.

**Problem: The zoom control is aligned at the bottom left which I would reposition it at bottom right corner.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Location button on map by getting parent view first and then "My Location" button as below :

```
// Get the "My Location" button view 
View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(1).getParent()).findViewById(2);

// get button params to place the button
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();

// place on right bottom corner
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
rlp.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
```

If want to resize button, you can get parameters like below :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
//.... do your editing
// To set params to button
locationButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Which language you are using for app?

Comment: I'm using Java.

Comment: Ohh.. i doesn't mean that language. In app, you are using any language that is right to left oriented? for example, English is left to right & Urdu, arabic are right to left

Comment: because if you are not using any language that is right to left oriented. You can set android:supportsRtl="false" to getting expected result.

Comment: Oh sorry!, I'm using Iran/Persian language (FA) in my app. By default, zoom controls are at bottom right corner but when I add `android:supportsRtl="true"` into the AndroidManifest file. it goes at the bottom left corner and I can't reposition it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161050/discussion-between-urvashi-bhalala-and-ahmad-payan).

Comment: once try to set it opposite. for example, set zp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT); to zoom control

Answer (score 0):

This code (based on [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38266867/6950238) answer of [Vignon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6565322/vignon)) :

```
void setConrolsPositions() {
    try {
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mMapFragment.getView().findViewWithTag("GoogleMapMyLocationButton").getParent();
        parent.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Resources r = getResources();
                    //convert our dp margin into pixels
                    int marginPixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, r.getDisplayMetrics());
                    // Get the map compass view

                    View mapLocation = mMapFragment.getView().findViewWithTag("GoogleMapMyLocationButton");

                    // create layoutParams, giving it our wanted width and height(important, by default the width is "match parent")
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mapLocation.getHeight(),
                            mapLocation.getHeight());
                    // position on top right
                    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
                    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
                    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                    //give compass margin
                    rlp.setMargins(marginPixels, marginPixels, marginPixels, marginPixels);
                    mapLocation.setLayoutParams(rlp);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

called from `onMapReady()`:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        int locationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            setConrolsPositions();
        } else {
            setConrolsPositions();
        }
    } else {
        setConrolsPositions();
    }
}
```

and `onRequestPermissionsResult()`:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                setConrolsPositions();
            } else {
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

worked for me:

[image: Map with changed controls positions]

without any `android:supportsRtl="true"` settings.